# zooming back in on Eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

while coding on Eclipse neon I must have accidentally hit something, to where the font for the entire code screen, and the console became really small to where it was illegible.  Please help; I tried to search this on google but couldn't find anything helpful.

thanks,
shereiza

Comment: can you include a picture so we know what exactly you are talking about?

Comment: Look out for Workspace preferences, font, java editor font. There should be a reset to default button somewhere.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572049/enlarging-font-size-in-console-output-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to zoom by pressing Ctrl+'+' while your code view is active.

Edit: 
To access the color and font settings, you might also try:
[Window] -> [Preferences] -> [General] -> [Appearance] -> [Colors and Fonts]

One of the options will be to restore all default settings, but you can also tweak each component individually.

Answer (score 1):

[CTRL] + [=]
or
[CTRL] + [+]

but do be sure to use the keyboard  + not the numpad one